# Android studio error "E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error: GL_INVALID_VALUE"

Tags: android, compiler-errors, invalidoperationexception, openglrenderer

I'm using a font which is some "playing cards" on a button and when i press the button, I change the caracter so the font change. Tu display all the 54 cards of a deck.

It works like 15 times and then I get an error and the font turns totally white, if I keep pressing it will always appear white until all the cards are done. I need to restart the app to see the font and it works 15~ times again. Like the 2nd picture below while it's supposed to look like the first one.

Anyone know why is it doing this and how can I fix that? I can post the error logs :

"
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_INVALID_VALUE

E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_VALUE

W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_INVALID_OPERATION

E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_OPERATION

D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_INVALID_OPERATION

E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_OPERATION

D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

W/Adreno-ES20: : GL_INVALID_OPERATION

E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  GL_INVALID_OPERATION
"

Thanks!

[What it supposed to look like (and looks like for the first 15th)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Jd6.png)

[When the bug happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aczU4.png)

Comment: Still can't find the solution if someone knows what I could've done wrong..

Comment: Did you get a solution???